# Why am I getting error: BC30452 Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'Image', for this code?

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

I have an application which has a **server** and a **client** file. On the server side, the server's camera (in my case, this is **my camera**), get's streamed to the client file, and then the clients camera (in my case, **my camera because I'm using this for educational purposes only**) get's streamed to the server file.

Right now I'm in the process of writing this program, but I'm getting an error when  I'm trying to stream the **client's camera**.

This is what the *client program* looks like:

[image]

Now, on the `Form_Load` sub, ***this*** code is declared

```
Public Class videocallfinal
    Public xxx As Integer
    Public Yy As String = "|U|"
    Dim pic As New Drawing.Bitmap(500, 400)
    Dim Touchless As New TouchlessLib.TouchlessMgr
    Dim camera1 As TouchlessLib.Camera = Touchless.Cameras.ElementAt(0)


     Private Sub videocallfinal_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        q.Comet.Send("camerastream" & Yy & PictureBox2.Image)
        PictureBox2.Image = camera1.GetCurrentImage
        Touchless.CurrentCamera = camera1
        Touchless.CurrentCamera.CaptureHeight = 130
        Touchless.CurrentCamera.CaptureWidth = 130
        Me.BringToFront()
        Me.Text = "You're currently in a video call with " + videocall.Label6.Text
        Label6.Text = videocall.Label6.Text
    End Sub
```

So, as you can see, I'm trying to send the PictureBox image to the server file on this line of code:

```
q.Comet.Send("camerastream" & Yy & PictureBox1.Image)
```

Under `PictureBox1.Image`, I get this error

> **BC30452 Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'Image'**.

I've done some re-search on this issue, but it's usually with different controls, and I've never dealt with an error like this **with a PictureBox**.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

*Thanks!*

Comment: `&` operator used for string concatenation, your `PictureBox2.Image` property has type of `System.Drawing.Bitmap` which cannot be concatenated directly. You should convert it to something like Base64 string and try concat it again, or use separate overload to accept `Image` as argument.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've used this code:    q.Comet.Send("camerastream" & Yy & System.Convert.ToBase64String(PictureBox2.Image)), to follow your instruction. However, I'm getting an error which says: BC30311 Value of type 'Image' cannot be converted to 'Byte()'. Did I not follow your instructions correctly? @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: @ZorinOSDevelopmentTeam where is `q` declared?

Comment: @Simo q is a separate form which handles the Server file sending requests for the webcam stream. Pretty much it's just the main form.

Comment: I think that a `Comet.Send` overload is the best way to go. something like `Comet.Send(string, string, image)`

Comment: @ZorinOSDevelopmentTeam You should avoid concatenating string and image at first place. Using separate 2 overload that accepts `Bitmap` type is more recommended.

Comment: How would I write this code out? (An example will do) @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: @Simo still giving me the same error even if I try it on the q form.

Comment: You have to overload the method `.Send` inside the Comet class i think

Comment: Dunno if you're able to create overload with `q.Comet.Send` (and doesn't know that method's content), but if it's created by yours, feel free to add its overload and process the image accordingly.

Comment: I'm guessing why this question got downvoted.

Comment: Yeah I don't see any reason why someone would downvote this question.. @Simo

Comment: To convert the image to a Base64 string, you need to turn it into bytes first.  There are two different `Save` overloads on `Image` that will write to a `Stream`; if you use a `MemoryStream` then you can get the resulting `Byte()` array.

Comment: Hi, Craig. Thank you for your comment. Could you please give me an example with the code I've provided? Thanks! @Craig

Comment: Before I do, just to confirm that it's really what you need, how are you getting the image loaded into the picture box?  Maybe there's an easier way if we take a different route.

Comment: Pretty much I'm using a Microsoft .dll which get's webcam capture. Pretty much, `camera1` is my camera, and then that get's applied to a PictureBox, and I send that PictureBox to the server file. @Craig

Comment: But yes, this is what I really need. A code example will be much appreciated. @Craig

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the image to a Base64 string by using a `MemoryStream` to get the bytes.  The following untested code, written from the docs for `MemoryStream` and `Image`, will do exactly this:

```
Dim s As New MemoryStream

PictureBox1.Image.Save(s, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)

Dim asBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(s.ToArray())
```

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for your response. I’ve tried your code, and it’s saying that “ImageFormat is not a member of System.Drawing” and it tries to correct it to ImageFormatConverter. Also, how do I send the image after I’ve saved it to a .bmp? @Craig

Comment: @ZorinOSDevelopmentTeam Sorry, I missed a namespace in the path to ImageFormat.  I've corrected this now.  Sorry, I can't help on how to send it.  You will have the image as a Base64 string in `asBase64` using this code, so it may just plug into the code in your question e.g. `q.Comet.Send("camerastream" & Yy & asBase64)` but I know nothing about whatever `Comet` might be in this case.

Comment: Hi Craig, that’s totally fine that you missed it. Thanks for your response.